# VSCode Debugger not working with FastAPI app in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, debugging, fastapi

I'm having trouble getting the debugger in VSCode to work with my FastAPI Python app that I run in a Docker container. I've packaged the app into a wheel file and installed it in the container by copying the wheel file over and then installing it.

My setup involves using debugpy to listen to `0.0.0.0:5678`, and I have set the VSCode debugger to listen to localhost port 5678. However, while the Docker container starts as expected, the FastAPI app doesn't seem to run.

Here is my `launch.json` configuration:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src/fast_api_app",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ],
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my `task.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "docker-build",
            "label": "docker-build development",
            "dockerBuild": {
                "context": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "file": "${workspaceFolder}/Dockerfile",
                "tag": "fastapiapp:debug",
                "remove": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "docker-run",
            "label": "docker-run: debug",
            "dependsOn": ["docker-build development"],
            "dockerRun": {
                "image": "fastapiapp:debug",
                "containerName": "fastapiapp-debug",
                "remove": true,
                "envFiles": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
                ],
                "ports": [
                    { "hostPort": 8000, "containerPort": 8000 , "protocol": "tcp"},
                    { "hostPort": 5678, "containerPort": 5678 , "protocol": "tcp"}
                ],
                "command": "python -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 --wait-for-client -m fast_api_app.main"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have followed many tutorials and suggestions but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the issue and resolve it myself. The problem was originating from the Dockerfile; it was still running the command specified in the `CMD [...]` directive.

Despite specifying a different command to run in the `task.json` file for the debug session, Docker was defaulting to the command from the Dockerfile, causing the application not to run as expected.

To solve the problem, I removed the `CMD [...]` directive from the Dockerfile. This allowed the Docker container to use the command specified in the `task.json` file when starting, enabling it to attach correctly to the VSCode debugger.

I hope this helps anyone else encountering a similar issue!